# Why Bootstrap's alert can close?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can someone explain for me, why an (bootstrap) alert can close when I clicked on (×):

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
</div>
```

- I've googled but result about used it.
- I've search in file: bootstrap.css, too. But what I want is understand how it run.
  Tks for reading it, sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap also has a JS part which handles such behaviours. You can even find a section regarding this in their [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts).

Comment: Ahh, thank your's answer, Aer0!
I just seen in CSS and don't know why. Now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

`(×)` is a button to close the alert. if you don't want the functionality then you can remove `data-dismiss="alert"` from `a` tag.

Comment: Tks you, Prince sodhi! Aer0 answered it :D

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer. Vote up and accept as right answer. It would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I haven't enough reputation to vote up, and I can't find button resolved. ( I'm newbie stackoverflow :| )